# FreeIPA - Login failed due to an unknown reason - SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, login, freeipa

I believe my FreeIPA instance has a certificate issue, which manifests in the "Login failed due to an unknown reason" error on the web ui. This seems to be really close to the issue described here: [Unable to log in to FreeIPA web ui - “Login failed due to an unknown reason.”](https://serverfault.com/questions/1032160/unable-to-log-in-to-freeipa-web-ui-login-failed-due-to-an-unknown-reason)

```
$ cat /var/log/httpd/error_log
[Sun Nov 15 03:36:02.557178 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 20540:tid 140295188322560] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Nov 15 03:36:02.574268 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 20540:tid 140295188322560] AH00489: Apache/2.4.39 (Fedora) OpenSSL/1.1.0i-fips mod_wsgi/4.5.20 Python/3.6 mod_auth_gssapi/1.6.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Nov 15 03:36:02.574356 2020] [core:notice] [pid 20540:tid 140295188322560] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sun Nov 15 03:36:17.130764 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16862:tid 140295188322560] ipa: INFO: *** PROCESS START ***
[Sun Nov 15 03:36:17.181095 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16863:tid 140295188322560] ipa: INFO: *** PROCESS START ***
[Sun Nov 15 03:36:17.370532 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16861:tid 140295188322560] ipa: INFO: *** PROCESS START ***
[Sun Nov 15 03:36:17.480511 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16864:tid 140295188322560] ipa: INFO: *** PROCESS START ***
[Sun Nov 15 15:12:18.414969 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16862:tid 140294055163648] [remote 10.6.0.156:49417] ipa: INFO: [jsonserver_i18n_messages] UNKNOWN: i18n_messages(version='2.230'): SUCCESS
[Mon Nov 16 16:50:51.133150 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16862:tid 140294055163648] [remote 10.5.30.3:59450] ipa: INFO: [jsonserver_i18n_messages] UNKNOWN: i18n_messages(version='2.230'): SUCCESS
[Mon Nov 16 16:51:15.363854 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16862:tid 140294055163648] [remote 10.5.30.3:59452] ipa: INFO: 401 Unauthorized: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ipa.mydomain.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ipa/session/cookie (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:877)'),))
[Wed Nov 18 16:58:58.647565 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16864:tid 140294055163648] [remote 10.0.10.3:41362] ipa: INFO: [jsonserver_i18n_messages] UNKNOWN: i18n_messages(version='2.230'): SUCCESS
[Wed Nov 18 16:59:07.206598 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16864:tid 140294055163648] [remote 10.0.10.3:41366] ipa: INFO: 401 Unauthorized: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ipa.mydomain.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ipa/session/cookie (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:877)'),))
[Wed Nov 18 17:23:49.225001 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16863:tid 140294055163648] [remote 10.5.30.3:34678] ipa: INFO: [jsonserver_i18n_messages] UNKNOWN: i18n_messages(version='2.230'): SUCCESS
[Wed Nov 18 17:24:12.026368 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16863:tid 140294055163648] [remote 10.5.30.3:34684] ipa: INFO: 401 Unauthorized: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ipa.mydomain.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ipa/session/cookie (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:877)'),))
[Wed Nov 18 17:34:59.981548 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 20540:tid 140295188322560] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Wed Nov 18 17:35:04.633179 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 8293:tid 140062174685440] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed Nov 18 17:35:04.734723 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 8293:tid 140062174685440] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed Nov 18 17:35:04.783843 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 8293:tid 140062174685440] AH00489: Apache/2.4.39 (Fedora) OpenSSL/1.1.0i-fips mod_wsgi/4.5.20 Python/3.6 mod_auth_gssapi/1.6.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 18 17:35:04.783971 2020] [core:notice] [pid 8293:tid 140062174685440] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Wed Nov 18 17:35:27.735404 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8302:tid 140062174685440] ipa: INFO: *** PROCESS START ***
[Wed Nov 18 17:35:28.647317 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8299:tid 140062174685440] ipa: INFO: *** PROCESS START ***
[Wed Nov 18 17:35:28.942391 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8300:tid 140062174685440] ipa: INFO: *** PROCESS START ***
[Wed Nov 18 17:35:29.517472 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8303:tid 140062174685440] ipa: INFO: *** PROCESS START ***
[Wed Nov 18 17:36:00.568524 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8302:tid 140061041526528] [remote 10.5.30.3:34818] ipa: INFO: 401 Unauthorized: kinit: Password incorrect while getting initial credentials
[Wed Nov 18 17:36:00.568690 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8302:tid 140061041526528] [remote 10.5.30.3:34818] 
[Wed Nov 18 17:36:03.647421 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8299:tid 140061041526528] [remote 10.5.30.3:34822] ipa: INFO: [jsonserver_i18n_messages] UNKNOWN: i18n_messages(version='2.230'): SUCCESS
[Wed Nov 18 17:36:16.136594 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8303:tid 140061041526528] [remote 10.5.30.3:34824] ipa: INFO: 401 Unauthorized: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ipa.mydomain.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ipa/session/cookie (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:877)'),))
[Wed Nov 18 20:00:01.556792 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8299:tid 140061041526528] [remote 10.5.30.3:35998] ipa: INFO: [jsonserver_i18n_messages] UNKNOWN: i18n_messages(version='2.230'): SUCCESS
[Thu Nov 19 12:58:54.813554 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8303:tid 140061041526528] [remote 10.5.30.3:50526] ipa: INFO: [jsonserver_i18n_messages] UNKNOWN: i18n_messages(version='2.230'): SUCCESS
[Thu Nov 19 12:59:13.712584 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8302:tid 140061041526528] [remote 10.5.30.3:50524] ipa: INFO: 401 Unauthorized: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ipa.mydomain.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ipa/session/cookie (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:877)'),))
```

This also seems to have the effect that some certificates cannot be verified(?):

```
$ ipa-getcert list
Request ID '20201010134403':
    status: MONITORING
    stuck: no
    key pair storage: type=NSSDB,location='/etc/dirsrv/slapd-mydomain-ORG',nickname='Server-Cert',token='NSS Certificate DB',pinfile='/etc/dirsrv/slapd-mydomain-ORG/pwdfile.txt'
    certificate: type=NSSDB,location='/etc/dirsrv/slapd-mydomain-ORG',nickname='Server-Cert',token='NSS Certificate DB'
    CA: IPA
    issuer: CN=Certificate Authority,O=mydomain.ORG
    subject: CN=ipa.mydomain.org,O=mydomain.ORG
    expires: 2022-10-02 15:40:17 CEST
    dns: ipa.mydomain.org
    principal name: ldap/ipa.mydomain.org@mydomain.ORG
    key usage: digitalSignature,nonRepudiation,keyEncipherment,dataEncipherment
    eku: id-kp-serverAuth,id-kp-clientAuth
    pre-save command: 
    post-save command: /usr/libexec/ipa/certmonger/restart_dirsrv mydomain-ORG
    track: yes
    auto-renew: yes
Request ID '20201010134408':
    status: CA_UNREACHABLE
    ca-error: Server at https://ipa.mydomain.org/ipa/xml failed request, will retry: -504 (HTTP POST to URL 'https://ipa.mydomain.org/ipa/xml' failed.  libcurl failed even to execute the HTTP transaction, explaining:  SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate).
    stuck: no
    key pair storage: type=FILE,location='/var/lib/ipa/private/httpd.key'
    certificate: type=FILE,location='/var/lib/ipa/certs/httpd.crt'
    CA: IPA
    issuer: OU=Me,CN=My-Server-CA,E=me@mydomain.de
    subject: OU=Me,CN=ipa.mydomain.org,E=me@mydomain.de
    expires: 2028-10-26 00:09:55 CEST
    dns: ipa.mydomain.org
    key usage: digitalSignature,keyEncipherment
    eku: id-kp-serverAuth,iso.org.dod.internet.security.mechanisms.8.2.2
    pre-save command: 
    post-save command: /usr/libexec/ipa/certmonger/restart_httpd
    track: yes
    auto-renew: yes
Request ID '20201010135651':
    status: CA_UNREACHABLE
    ca-error: Server at https://ipa.mydomain.org/ipa/xml failed request, will retry: -504 (HTTP POST to URL 'https://ipa.mydomain.org/ipa/xml' failed.  libcurl failed even to execute the HTTP transaction, explaining:  SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate).
    stuck: no
    key pair storage: type=FILE,location='/var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kdc.key'
    certificate: type=FILE,location='/var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kdc.crt'
    CA: IPA
    issuer: CN=Certificate Authority,O=mydomain.ORG
    subject: CN=ipa.mydomain.org,O=mydomain.ORG
    expires: 2022-10-11 15:57:42 CEST
    principal name: krbtgt/mydomain.ORG@mydomain.ORG
    key usage: digitalSignature,nonRepudiation,keyEncipherment,dataEncipherment
    eku: id-kp-serverAuth,id-pkinit-KPKdc
    certificate template/profile: KDCs_PKINIT_Certs
    pre-save command: 
    post-save command: /usr/libexec/ipa/certmonger/renew_kdc_cert
    track: yes
    auto-renew: yes
```

Does anyone have an idea which certificate is causing this problem?